# Survive segmentation fault with "rake test"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, segmentation-fault, rake, minitest

I have some Rails tests, using Minitest, which unfortunately trigger a segfault. This breaks execution of remaining tests.

Until I can fix the segfaults, what's a performant way to ensure "rake test" will run all tests instead of aborting on the first encounter of a segfault?

Comment: can you add the segfault logs to the question?

Comment: They are documented here https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/842 but my question is intended to be general, relating to any segfault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The neversaydie gem will let you rescue from segmentation faults: [neversaydie gem](https://github.com/tenderlove/neversaydie).